# How to access SOAP message elements?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, soap

So i am trying to replace the values of username and password in the XML file containing a SOAP message. Here are the elements:

```
 <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-68f84594-d592-470b-9bbc-b29f58b4756f-1">
            <o:Username></o:Username>
            <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"></o:Password>
        </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
```

Basically, i want to take the username and password values from my config file, and place them in the username and password fields within the XML file containing the soap message. This is my attempt, and it throws a NPE at the docElement.getElementsByTagName lines:

```
 public void updateUserDetails() {
    final Properties configProperties = new Properties();
    try {
        configProperties.load(new FileInputStream(PROPERTIES));
        final Document requestDoc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream(SOAP_REQUEST));
        final Element docElement = requestDoc.getDocumentElement();
        docElement.getElementsByTagName("Username").item(0).setTextContent(configProperties.getProperty("username"));
        docElement.getElementsByTagName("Password").item(0).setTextContent(configProperties.getProperty("password"));
    } catch(IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException exception) {
        LOGGER.error("There was an error loading the properties file", exception);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Which line throws NPE?

Comment: @aUserHimself Sorry, forgot to add that. The two docElement.getElementsByName statements throw the NPE

Comment: But is it on `docElement.getElementsByTagName("Username")` or on `configProperties.getProperty("username")`?

Comment: @aUserHimself Yes it is. If i remove that line, then it throws an NPE at the docElement.getElementsByName("Password") statement as well.

Comment: I meant: is it a problem with the tag name (`docElement.getElementsByTagName("Username")`) OR with the property name that is not found (`configProperties.getProperty("username")`)? Try putting both of them on a debugger expression evaluator and see which one throws NPE.

Comment: @aUserHimself. Just tested. configProperties.getProperty("username") does not throw an NPE when printed out. Neither does configProperties.getProperty("password").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be related to a namespace problem.
Try specifying the namespace for your tag:

```
String namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
final Document requestDoc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream(SOAP_REQUEST));
docElement.getElementsByTagNameNS(namespace, "Username").item(0).setTextContent(configProperties.getProperty("username"));
docElement.getElementsByTagNameNS(namespace, "Password").item(0).setTextContent(configProperties.getProperty("password"));
```

Also, don't forget in the end to write the result back to file:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance(); 
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(); 
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(requestDoc); 
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File(SOAP_REQUEST)); 
transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you for your help in chat as well.